# Executing tasks while app is active and in background

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, background

I need to scan a website for changes every few minutes and when difference occurs i need inform user with popout window that contains information about that change.

Problem is i can't find solution to that, i tried putting that code in applicationDidEnterBackground but it didnt work. I'm new to swift and mobile programming at all so please be understanding.

Where should i begin? Little tip maybe.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't really want to do that in-app. Consider using a 3rd party service (like kingdom for example) to trigger push notifications instead.

Comment: Is your app going to be distributed in Appstore? Apple is really strict on allowing your app to execute in background and most apps do not qualify. If your app is going to Appstore the best approach would be using push notifications with `content-available` flag.

Comment: No, its only for my university excercise, and only in simulator :)